# Mocking deep objects in Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to achieve the following :

```
Class A{
List<Class B> list;
}

Class B{
}

@Mock
A a;
when(a.list.isEmpty()).then(true); // this throws an error
```

By using this :

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
A a;
```

I have to use a getter :

```
when(a.getList().isEmpty()).then(true);
```

But I don't want to change my code to use getters everywhere..

Comment: I'm afraid you don't really have a choice (unless you do something like `a.list = mock(...);` at some point).

Comment: If you want the list to be empty for the purposes of your test, then can't you just use an empty list, and not mock anything?  Seriously though, use getters.  Otherwise you'll run into far more problems than just this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mock direct access to a member variable.  So you have a few options:

1. Use a getter.
2. Set the member variable to be a mock instance (`a.list = mock(...)` or equivalent).
3. In the case of a trivial class like a list, there's marginal value to using a mock as you can more or less directly set up the behaviour you want.  So in this case, `a.list = new ArrayList<>();` would suffice.